# How to display tictactoe board using map and forEach?

Tags: java, collections, java-8

I want to display tic tac toe board. Something like that:

```
XXX
XXX
XXX
```

Is it possible to use for each to achieve that?
I tried to do some:

```
    Map<Integer, Tile> board = generateBoard();

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Tile> entry: board.entrySet()){
        System.out.print(entry.getValue().getSign());
    }

    board.forEach((k,v) -> {
        int i = 1;
        if(i % 3 == 0){
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.print(v.getSign());
        i++;
    });
```

But my output is incorrect. Could you give me any output to achieve me this output?

Comment: What do you mean by incorrect? Also could you please provide a [minimum, complete, verifiable, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Read the code you wrote in plain English. *Set i equal to one. Test to see if one modulo three is zero, and if so call println. Call print, and then add one to i. Then go back to Set i equal to one.* Does that seem right to you?

Answer (score 1):

One obvious problem is that `i` isn't incremented because you're redefining it on each iteration. Unfortunately, labmdas and stateful variables don't mix well. I would suggest using a regular `for` loop instead:

```
int i = 0;
for (Tile tile : board.values()) {
    System.out.print(tile.getSign());
    if (++i % 3 == 0) {
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. Your i will never increment, as it is declared within the loop. It will always be 1.
2. If you have "k" (the index) why are you creating a new index?

Remove i and replace it with k and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Variables referenced inside lambda from outside the lambda must be [Effectively Final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732544/why-are-only-final-variables-accessible-in-anonymous-class/4732617#4732617) or final. This prevents you from easily incrementing a counter remembering where you are up to.

Assuming that the integer key in your map, is the slot number you can do this.

```
 board.forEach((k,v) -> {
        System.out.print(v.getSign());
        if(k % 3 == 0){
            System.out.println();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Variables *inside* lambdas are **not** effectively final. Variables *outside* lambdas may only be referenced *within* them if they're final or effectively final.

Comment: Thanks. I've edited to make the language I used more clear.